# df.loc[] with multiple callables

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to do a lookup in a DataFrame using two separate Callables (one provided by the user, one by param). Also acceptable: Index by one Callable and another filter using the explicit syntax.

Is this possible? I'm guessing it could be done with groupby, but that seems a bit cumbersome.

Minimal code sample:

```
import pandas as pd  # Version: 0.23.4, Python 2.7
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [1, 2,1], 'C2': [3, 4, 10]})


# This works
filter = lambda adf: adf['C1']==1
df.loc[filter]

# So does this
df.loc[df['C2']>5]

# Both of them together works
df.loc[(df['C2']>5) & (df['C1']==1)]

# So why don't any of these?
df.loc[(df['C2']>5) & filter] #TypeError: ...
df.loc[(df['C2']>5) & (filter)] # TypeError: ...
df.loc[df['C2']>5 & filter] # TypeError: ...

filter2 = lambda adf: adf['C2']>5
df.loc[(filter) & (filter2)] # TypeError: ...
df.loc[(filter) | (filter2)] # TypeError: ...

# Nesting works, but isn't pretty for multiple callables
df.loc[(df['C2']>5)].loc[filter]
```

Comment: filter is a function. You need to call it by `filter(df)`: try `df.loc[(df['C2']>5) & (filter(df))]`

Comment: Thanks @Chris! This works under the assumption that filter(df) == df.loc[filter]. I haven't yet wrapped my head around whether that is always true.

Comment: @MagO the error isn't caused by the way you're indexing, it's caused by the bitwise AND operation.  what @Chris suggested creates a boolean mask to avoid the `TypeError`

Comment: @MagO another option is creating an encompassing callable: `df.loc[lambda x: filter(x) & (x['C2'] > 5)]` that uses the previously created callable

Comment: Maybe you notice that `filter` has a different color in the syntax highlighting. This is because there's already a python builtin function called [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)! Best to not use this as a variable name, unfortunately, because it overrides the builtin locally.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass your lambda `filter` as a `loc` parameter, you are passing it like an object function, and not as a result of computation of that function.

For this reason you can't use any `logical operator` to combine multiple function, unlike what happens when you use multiple `logical` criteria.

In any case, if you want to use heterogeneous criteria (logical and functional) for filter you dataframe, you can use `loc` twice. as you yourself suggest.

```
# function
filter = lambda df: df['C1']==1
df.loc[(df['C2']>5)].loc[filter]
```